# suggest JavaScript непрозрачное поле

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

Проблема в следующем. 
Использую скрипт:

```
var haystack = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", ...];

$(function(){   $('#query').suggest(haystack, {
    suggestionColor   : '#cccccc',
    moreIndicatorClass: 'suggest-more',
    moreIndicatorText : '&hellip;' 
});
```

для поля:

```
<input class="query" id="query" name="q" type="text" /></pre>
```

Но при запуске скрипта на странице получаю такое поле: [image: Поле input]

И возможность ввести текст есть только, есть нажать на чуть заметное расстояние(тень). При том, что совершенно не видно, что ты вводишь, но если вводить в эту "прослойку", то подбор происходит верно и выглядит это так:

[image: Поле 2]

Т.е. вывод подсказок верный, но поле input перестает быть обычным полем из-за подставленного скриптом div. [image: div]
Если удалить этот div, то остается обычное поле input, но и подсказки, которые заполняются в этом div исчезают.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как ее исправить? В JS я новичок и только учусь. Если есть какой то другой похожий и бесплатный функционал - буду очень признателен за подсказки.

**UPD.** Если в свойствах div убрать position : absolute, то наложение этих элементов убирается, но "подсказки" тогда выводятся снизу, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы это было из разряда: [image: поле 3] . Делаю все, как из этого примера, но результат должный не получается.

**UPD2**. Ссылка на используемую библиотеку [suggest](http://polarblau.github.io/suggest/).

Comment: А вы добавили `css` файлы для библиотеки `suggest`?

Comment: Покажите, какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, css не добавлял, но в "мануале" про это и не сказано. Использую jquery.suggest.js от polarblau гитхаб ио

Comment: Ссылочку дайте на библиотеку, пожалуйста. А css с 90% вероятностью нужен. И добавьте эту информацию  в вопрос!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал вам не использовать подобные библиотеки:

1. Мало рейтинга
2. Давно не обновлялась
3. Явно не рабочее демо

Ошибка была в стилях для **input**.

Посмотрите рабочий пример.

```js
var haystack = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC"];

$(function() {
  $('#search').suggest(haystack, {
    suggestionColor: '#cccccc',
    moreIndicatorClass: 'suggest-more',
    moreIndicatorText: '&hellip;'
  });
});
```

```css
#search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-suggest/src/jquery.suggest.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваша правка работает! 
А что бы Вы порекомендовали использовать в моем случае? Рад любой наводке :) Смотрел у яндекса suggest для карт, но необходим API-ключ.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр спасибо принимается в виде приянтого ответа :) Что бы что-то посоветовать, надо знать ваши требования.

Comment: Слишком обрадовался работающему варианту и забыл жмакнуть галочку, приношу свои извинения, исправился. У меня сервер на JAVA, откуда я передаю JSON (ну или чем угодно, без разницы) массив, строку (что угодно) с возможными вариантами. Необходимо, соответственно, когда пользователь начинает вводить текст - нужно выводить в таком же виде возможные варианты из тех, что пришли с сервера.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр Я больше спрашивал про требования к самому компоненту, который должен показывать подсказки. Внешний вид, поддержка клавиатуры, поведение. Есть решение от `bootstrap` или можно нативно сделать с помощью `datalist`.

Comment: Хм, компонент - input поле, внешний вид - чем красивше, тем лучше :D . Языки английский и русский (что Вы имели в виду под поддержкой клавиатуры?). Поведение - подсказки должны быть именно такого же вида, как suggest, а не просто выпадающий список, из которого можно выбрать.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр Красивость - понятие глубоко субъективное. Ищите в интернете, пробуйте. Смотрите на рейтинг, на поддержку, как быстро закрываются issue. Никто кроме вас не знает, что вам точно надо. Поэтому советовать что-то определенное - бесполезно.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. Спасибо за помощь! :)